# how to execute a javascript code right after a function has been defined?

Tags: javascript, function

For example, there is a function like:

```
function something(a,b,c,d){/*its defined*/}
```

I would need a javascript code to execute right after the function has been created.

Simply `"if(typeof functionName == 'function')"` wont do, since that wont execute right after its defined. It would need to be something like an event listener, executing right when it sees the function having been created.

Oh, and I CANNOT edit the function, and can NOT paste javascript right after it. its in an external javascript file I CANT edit.

Why I need this is because I need to overwrite the function right after it is defined, before it is called, but I don't know when it is called, and I probably can't edit that part either. Its probably only created right before it is called.

Comment: you can use a library like `Require.js` to load this javascript, and get an event immediately as it's loads.

Comment: you mean to load the entire javascript file? or the function? what i meant is, i cant do anything with it. all i can do is paste new javascript on the page. but not the external file.

Comment: I mean that you could load the entire script file via `require`

Answer (score -1):

A sample is below.

```
(function something(a,b,c,d){
    //its defined
 })(); // its executed immediately.
```

This is called IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression

Comment: why downvote.. please put a comment so I can understand too

Comment: it wasnt me who downvoted... but wouldnt your solution need me to change the external javascript file? i cant do anything with it, i cant write anything before or after the function.

Comment: I meant whoever has downvoted, should have put comment. If the external function itself is IIFE then you cant change its definition before any call to it

Comment: Just a suggestion, Instead of going deep in this approach try some other way to do your required stuff

Comment: how can i determine if its IIFE or not? actually, the function also seems to be deleted after its ran. and the external javascript file start like this: (function(){ does that mean its "IIFE"?

Comment: yes.. you are right.. if the function is not accessible after its run then most probably thats IIFE

Comment: and there is no way to overwrite that? or change it in any way, real time or not?